# Adding icon button to column headers for ControlsFX TableFilter

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

I have implemented the open-source [ControlsFX TableFilter](http://fxexperience.com/2016/03/introducing-the-controlsfx-tablefilter/) on a project that I am working on.

If you take a look at the documentation, you realize that there is no icon that lets the user know that there is a filter option for a column. Instead, you have to right click a column header in order to activate the filter functionality. Obviously, this is not the best in terms of usability - a user has to be explicitly told that right clicking will activate the filter functionality, otherwise they have no idea of knowing.

My question is, is there a way to implement an icon button for each column header that would activate the TableFilter? An example would be this [project](https://github.com/jhsheets/javafx-filterable-table-columns).

You notice that with this implementation, the hourglass icon is clearly shown to the user. However, this project does not contain any of the behind-the-scenes logic implementation required for the filter, while the ControlsFX one has that all taken care of. If there is a way to add the GitHub project's style column header hourglass icon to the ControlsFX filter, I would greatly appreciate a solution! Thank you so much!

Comment: the second just uses the tableColumn's graphic - why not simply do the same in the first?

Comment: ... And how would you turn that graphic into a button, and then add functionality to activate the ControlsFX filter?

Comment: don't understand .. if it's a button, set its actionHandler and trigger the filtering of controlsfx

Comment: The ControlsFX table filter automatically does everything for you though - ie. to apply the filter:

`TableBuilder.TableFilter.forTableView(table).apply()`

This automatically applies filters for every single column. How could you set an actionHandler to activate the filter, when almost all the filter's mechanisms are behind the scenes? The only code you have to add in for the ControlsFX filter is the line above.

Comment: the _min_ you have to do ;) There must be api that triggers that magic, read the code, find it and hook into ...

Comment: just checked: controlsfx tableFilter has a rather weird design (to put it mildly ;) - there is no hook that I could find to open those filters: so you need to get inventive: they are placed inside the column's contextMenu, so your button has to open the contextMenu. A bit involved to find the correct coordinates ... too lazy right now ..

Comment: I looked all day yesterday and did not find a good solution.... doesn't help that none of the code is commented either

Answer (score 1):

Note: this is not a complete answer to the question - just a slightly flashed out comment on how to hook into controlsfx TableFilter!

The task in the question is modify controlsfx TableFilter such that

- each column has a visual element to indicate that it is filterable
- activating that visual element should open the filter to allow user input

By default, the column has no indicator and the filter panel is opened by right clicking into the header.

My first idea - use a button as graphic and start filtering in its action handler - turned out to be not as straightforward as I expected: TableFilter doesn't seem to have any api to access column filters or to trigger/start filtering programmatically (or maybe I simply didn't find it).

Exploiting the implementation detail that the filter ui is shown in the column's contextMenu a working approach in the action handler is something like

- find the TableColumnHeader (aka: the Region that's the visual representation of the column)
- find the screen coordinates of that region
- open the column's contextMenu

The snippet below is a PoC for fx8 (internals did change considerable for fx9!) and can be tested by copying into the FlightTable example:

```
Button filterButton = new Button("Y");
filterButton.setOnAction(e -> {
    TableHeaderRow header = ((TableViewSkin<?>) table.getSkin()).getTableHeaderRow();
    TableColumnHeader columnHeader = header.getColumnHeaderFor(flightNumCol);
    Bounds localBounds = columnHeader.getBoundsInLocal();
    double xl = (localBounds.getMaxX() - localBounds.getMinX()) / 2;
    double yl = localBounds.getMaxY();
    Point2D p = columnHeader.localToScreen(xl, yl);
    flightNumCol.getContextMenu().show(table, p.getX(), p.getY());
});
flightNumCol.setGraphic(filterButton);
```

---

Doesn't really work: the graphic is used by TableFilter to mark a column as being filtered. We might grab that graphic and hook a mouse handler on it to allow opening the filter ui ... but from a UX perspective that's terrible as there would be one icon with two roles ...

Comment: The solution does seem to work initially, but TableFilter seems to hijack TableColumns in some way - the moment a filter is applied, the Y button disappears and there is no way to get it back after that point.

Comment: arrghh .. see what happens: the graphic is used to mark a column as being filtered ... hmm ...

Comment: Perhaps you need to find a way to show that same button instead of the filter graphic when a column is being filtered?